# How to pack module into module with the same name with ocamlopt?

Tags: compilation, nested, ocaml, stack-overflow, packing

In OCaml, I can create module with nested module with the same name.

```
module X = struct
  module X = struct
    let x = 42
  end
end
```

Also I can pack it with **ocamlc**:

```
ocamlc -for-pack X -c X.ml

mkdir tmp
mv X.cmo tmp/X.cmo
mv X.cmi tmp/X.cmi

ocamlc -pack -o X.cmo t/X.cmo
```

But when I try to do it with **ocamlopt** I have:

> Fatal error: exception Stack overflow

after make file run.

How I can pack module into module with the same name with **ocamlopt**?

Comment: You cannot do it. `ocamlopt` assumes the packed and target modules have different names...

Comment: This case looks like theoretical research, but I have real task with code generation and modules tree building, and sometimes I have packed and target modules with same name and have no possibility to change this name.

Comment: The problem still exists in OCaml 4.09

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in ocamlopt. Please report this upstream.

If packing a module X into a pack X isn't allowed then the compiler should say so. If it's allowed then it should work. Either way the Stack overflow is a bug.

Comment: The problem still exists in OCaml 4.09. I created bug request: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/issues/9776